# Content not refreshing in Google assistant, but works fine in Dialog Flow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have been searching so long for this, and couldn't find a solution.

So, I have developed a pretty basic dialog flow project and deployed it onto firebase using inline editor. 
Now the 1st deployment works perfectly fine with the simulator. 
However, I changed some content to include suggestion chips and modify the responses as well; this gets reflected fine in dialog flow. And I can see the changes I have made.

But when I update the Draft and try to test it again in simulator/google assistant device, it doesn't load the newer changes. I am not sure if what I am doing is correct or not. 
Please help :(

Just now found this - https://discuss.api.ai/t/actions-on-google-integration-agent-updates-do-not-always-publish-correctly/7483

It seems many users are facing this issue.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow had a bug causing this issue which should now be fixed.

Comment: It seems issue still exists in 2021 in other form, as I am also facing this in one of the existing project. Previously "Auto-preview" was coming in dialog flow under integration section, but Google discontinued to this option from 14 April 2021. Please suggest if any alternative is avalable.
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes#April_14_2021

And, as new tool Action Builder has been introduced, it seems they are intimating developers to migrate to Action Builder now, instead of continue using DialogFlow.